# ASP.NET json serializer only includes __type for top level class

Tags: asp.net, json

I'm using [webmethod] attribute in an aspx page to expose a complex data structure(autogenerated from xml->xsd->xsd.exe) to the browser.

After I get the data on the client with jquery, only the top level object includes the "__type" attribute, so I cannot determine the class of any of the nested objects(attributes, array content etc).

Is there a way to make the asp.net serializer include the __type attribute recursively when serializing an object?

Comment: You don't in general need it. Knowing the top-type should enable you to know all the others because of the static typing in all the types. So to deserialize you only need the top type.

Comment: Well, in my case the generated classes included an object[] which contains different classes... So I beg to differ ;-)

Comment: P.S. To be specific, this data is the ruleset dumped from biztalk on xml format.

Comment: Which serializer are you using?

Comment: And also, yeah, `Object` tends to throw a wrench into knowledge about static types... Didn't consider that.

Comment: I'm just decorating a static method in the codebehind with "Webmethod", so I suppose there is a "builtin" json asp.net serializer...

Comment: Hmm. I haven't used that serializer, so I'm afraid I won't be of much help.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar situation with another JSON serializer, the one from ServiceStack.Text. They will put in the `__type` property if an object is declared as an interface or an abstract class, perhaps the vanilla .NET serializer will do so as well? If that's the case, is there any way for you to declare your object[] array as an array of interfaces? Even something as trivial as cerating an `IEmpty` with no methods will do the trick.